# Script for dualizing diagrams in tikzcd by mirroring

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams, scripts

My question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384552/script-for-dualizing-diagrams-in-tikzcd), but in some cases I would prefer my diagrams to be mirrored instead of rotated. Is it possible to write a script which achieves this in LaTeX? As an example I have this diagram for the product:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
C \arrow[rr] \arrow[drr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[ddrr]
\arrow[dd, "\exists! \Phi", dashed] && \vdots \\
&& F(x) \\
\prod F \arrow[uurr] \arrow[urr, "\pi_x", swap] \arrow[rr] && \vdots
\end{tikzcd}
```

and its dual, the coproduct:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\vdots \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddrr] && C \\
F(x) \arrow[urr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[drr, "\mu_x", swap] \\
\vdots \arrow[uurr]\arrow[rr] && \coprod F \arrow[uu, "\exists ! \Phi", dashed]
\end{tikzcd}
```

I had an attempt at modifying the script in the accepted answer of the linked question, but failed to produce a solution.
*Thanks!*

Comment: There is a bounty for you. Please if the work of the great user for you is very good, check and put also the green v below the score. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simple diagrams like this you only need to set the `column sep` to a negative value, swap the labels, and revert the arrows. The negative value here was found by looking at the manual. Significantly more complex, where complex means varying column widths, reverted arrows and so on, diagrams may not be dualized that easily. (One can still write styles that revert all relevant original keys to their "dualized" values but the effort for this may not be justified.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{dual/.style={column sep=#1,every label/.append style={swap},
arrows=leftarrow},
dual/.default=-5.5em}
\begin{document}
Original diagram:
\[\begin{tikzcd}
C \arrow[rr] \arrow[drr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[ddrr]
\arrow[dd, "\exists! \Phi", dashed] && \vdots \\
&& F(x) \\
\prod F \arrow[uurr] \arrow[urr, "\pi_x", swap] \arrow[rr] && \vdots
\end{tikzcd}\]
Dual constructed by hand"
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\vdots \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddrr] && C \\
F(x) \arrow[urr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[drr, "\mu_x", swap] \\
\vdots \arrow[uurr]\arrow[rr] && \coprod F \arrow[uu, "\exists ! \Phi", dashed]
\end{tikzcd}\]
Dual constructed by adding the pgf key \texttt{dual} to the original diagram.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[dual]
C \arrow[rr] \arrow[drr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[ddrr]
\arrow[dd, "\exists! \Phi", dashed] && \vdots \\
&& F(x) \\
\prod F \arrow[uurr] \arrow[urr, "\pi_x", swap] \arrow[rr] && \vdots
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How could make this things easier? You could just store the original diagram in a macro (using an appropriate `ampersand replacement`) and then dualize it reusing the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{dual/.style={column sep=#1,every label/.append style={swap},
arrows=leftarrow},dual/.default=-5.5em,ampersand replacement=\&}
\begin{document}
\def\OriginalDiagram{C \arrow[rr] \arrow[drr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[ddrr]
\arrow[dd, "\exists! \Phi", dashed] \&\& \vdots \\
\&\& F(x) \\
\prod F \arrow[uurr] \arrow[urr, "\pi_x", swap] \arrow[rr] \&\& \vdots
}
Original diagram:
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\OriginalDiagram
\end{tikzcd}\]
Dual constructed by adding the pgf key \texttt{dual} to the original diagram.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[dual]
\OriginalDiagram
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that this duality does not turn a `\pi` into a `\mu` and a `\prod` into a `\coprod`.

Comment: In the meantime, thank you very much for helping the user. I'm sorry I can't vote now but I finished all the votes.

Comment: I hope that the user not forgot to put the green tick as approved. For me it is a form of justice for your great work.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the bounty! (Whether this is precisely what the user wants we still need to find out...)

Comment: I'm not interested in the votes :-) and I'm very happy to have assigned it to a competent user like you.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer and additional insight into the topic! This was exactly what I was looking for and more. Sorry if I was slow to accept, but I did not have time to read and try out your solution earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I could add something to the conversation by noting that you can similarly to the accepted answer set `row sep` to a negative value to mirror the diagram horizontally. Though the original question described vertical mirroring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{vdual/.style={column sep=#1,every label/.append style={swap},
arrows=leftarrow},
vdual/.default=-5.5em, ampersand replacement=\&}
\tikzcdset{hdual/.style={row sep=#1,every label/.append style={swap},
arrows=leftarrow},
hdual/.default=-5.5em, ampersand replacement=\&}

\begin{document}
\def\OriginalDiagram{C \arrow[rr] \arrow[drr, "\phi_x"] \arrow[ddrr]
\arrow[dd, "\exists! \Phi", dashed] \&\& \vdots \\
\&\& F(x) \\
\prod F \arrow[uurr] \arrow[urr, "\pi_x", swap] \arrow[rr] \&\& \vdots
}
Original diagram:
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\OriginalDiagram
\end{tikzcd}\]

Dual constructed by adding the pgf key \texttt{vdual} to the original diagram.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[vdual]
\OriginalDiagram
\end{tikzcd}\]

Dual constructed by adding the pgf key \texttt{hdual} to the original diagram.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[hdual]
\OriginalDiagram
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Apologies if I'm not following etiquette.

Comment: Also your answer is good.