# reorder matrix rows for tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-matrix

I have a tikz matrix, I'd like to reorder the rows from top to bottom to bottom to top

```
\matrix
{
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  g & h & i\\
}
```

to

```
\matrix
{
  g & h & i\\
  d & e & f\\
  a & b & c\\
}
```

Of course I can do it by hand for simple cases but I have a lot of matrices that might change. I'd like some reordering macro. The end of line delimes are by \ so it probably could be quite easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Arbitrary permutations of matrix entries**

If you want to permute matrix entries, this can be done as follows. Here is a proof of principle, which works. You define a matrix, and save it via

```
\matrix[matrix of nodes,save cells=A]
{
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  g & h & i\\
};
```

where `A` serves an identifier (in case you have several matrices). This matrix can be recast in a permuted form using

```
\matrix[xshift=3cm,matrix of nodes,declare function={mati(\i,\j)=4-\i;
matj(\i,\j)=\j;},reorder cells=A]
{
   &  & \\
   &  & \\
   &  & \\
};
```

Here the functions `mati(\i,\j)` and `matj(\i,\j)` define the mapping of the row index `\i` and the column index `\j`. In this case at hand, it just reverts the ordering of the rows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{save cells/.style={cells={nodes={execute at begin
node={\ifcsname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
\else%
\expandafter\newbox\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
\fi%
\expandafter\expandafter\global\setbox\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname=\hbox\bgroup},
execute at end
node={\egroup%
\expandafter\copy\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
}}}},
reorder cells/.style={nodes in empty cells,
cells={nodes={execute at begin
node={
\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup},
execute at end
node={\egroup%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mati(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myj}{matj(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}%
%\typeout{(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)->(\myi,\myj)}%
\expandafter\copy\csname matrixcellbox#1-\myi-\myj\endcsname%
}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,save cells=A]
{
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  g & h & i\\
};
\matrix[xshift=3cm,matrix of nodes,declare function={mati(\i,\j)=4-\i;
matj(\i,\j)=\j;},reorder cells=A]
{
   &  & \\
   &  & \\
   &  & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

At the expense of even more complex style definitions, one can spare the user from having to enter an empty matrix by employing [these routines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60400). Of course, one can also make the nodes math. The mapping is also slightly more complex in this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\CreateEmptyMatrix}[3]{% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60400
\xdef#3{}%
  \foreach \j in {1,...,#1}{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\the\numexpr#2-1} {%
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
         \noexpand\gappto\noexpand#3{ {} \&}}\x
      }%
    \gappto#3{\\}%
  }
}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{save cells/.style={cells={nodes={execute at begin
node={\ifcsname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
\else%
\expandafter\newbox\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
\fi%
\expandafter\expandafter\global\setbox\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname=\hbox\bgroup},
execute at end
node={\egroup%
\expandafter\copy\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
}}},
execute at end matrix={%
\expandafter\xdef\csname matrix@rows@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname matrix@colss@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}%
}},
save math cells/.style={cells={nodes={execute at begin
node={\ifcsname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
\else%
\expandafter\newbox\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
\fi%
\expandafter\expandafter\global\setbox\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname=\hbox\bgroup$},
execute at end
node={$\egroup%
\expandafter\copy\csname matrixcellbox#1-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\endcsname%
}}},
execute at end matrix={%
\expandafter\xdef\csname matrix@rows@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname matrix@cols@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}%
}},
reorder cells/.style={/utils/exec=%
\edef\myrows{\csname matrix@rows@#1\endcsname}%
\edef\mycols{\csname matrix@cols@#1\endcsname}%
\CreateEmptyMatrix{\myrows}{\mycols}{\myemptymatrix},
ampersand replacement=\&,
node contents=\myemptymatrix,
nodes in empty cells,
cells={nodes={execute at begin
node={
\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup},
execute at end
node={\egroup%
\edef\myrows{\csname matrix@rows@#1\endcsname}%
\edef\mycols{\csname matrix@cols@#1\endcsname}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{max(1,min(\myrows,mati(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)))}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myj}{max(1,min(\mycols,matj(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)))}%
%\typeout{(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)->(\myi,\myj)}%
\expandafter\copy\csname matrixcellbox#1-\myi-\myj\endcsname%
}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,save math cells=A]
{
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  g & h & i\\
};
\matrix[xshift=3cm,matrix of nodes,
declare function={mati(\i,\j)=4-\i;
matj(\i,\j)=4-\j;},reorder cells=A]
{
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one may suppress the output of the first matrix, e.g. by shooting it into a box that we never use.

**OLDER ANSWER**: This effect can be achieved by dialing negative `row sep`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{swap rows/.style={row sep=-3em,yshift=1em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes]
{
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  g & h & i\\
};
\matrix[xshift=3cm,matrix of math nodes,swap rows]
{
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  g & h & i\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar tricks have been used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508091/194703) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508394/194703).