# Dual commutative diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I use `tikz-cd` to draw my commutative diagrams, like the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=scriptsize]
            0 \rar & X \dar["\tilde p", hook, dashed] \rar["x", hook]\ar["\scriptscriptstyle(*)", phantom, dr] & Y \dar["p", two heads]\rar["y", two heads] & Z \dar[equal]\rar & 0\\
            0 \rar & U \rar["u"', hook] & V \rar["v"', two heads] & W \rar & 0
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to draw the picture for the dual diagram, which is obtained by the following transformations:

- hooks and double headed tips are exchanged.
- labels of dashed arrows obtain a prime, unless:
- they have a bar or a tilde. In this case, bars and tildes are exchanged.
- $x$- and $y$-coordinates are inverted.

Is it possible to just write down the primal diagram and let Ti*k*Z build the dual one automatically?

Comment: Maybe it's possible, but you employ (waste?) more time in trying to do it than to retype the diagram. Side note: I believe that `\arrow[r,<other options>]` is clearer than `\rar` `\dar` and similar.

Comment: @egreg That's probably true; I just have to wonder how to best write the diagrams in such a way that if I change one, it's easy to find the necessary elements to change in the other.

Comment: Can you please enhance the example so that's is compilable? Starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`. That well make it easier to experiment with your code, without having to guess the packages loaded and so on... Thanks!

Comment: @Rmano Sorry; changed.

Comment: Maybe you can start from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508091).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Indeed, that looks like a good starting point. Sorry for not having found this by myself!